# Click on Android notification doesn't show activity selector

Tags: android, notifications

**Explanation:** 
     I have used Daemon Thread.
      In my application when user send any file (.jpg,.txt,.pdf etc) then it will generate the individual notifications for every file.
      Suppose there are 3 notifications.
      When user Tap on any of Notifications then it will call the `android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW` according to the file and suggest openwith option.

**Problem:**
      When user select notification it will be opened in respective application(e.g If user selects sample.txt then it will be opened in colornote)and 
      after that when user tap on another notification then it will do nothing and onwards same thing happens.

I have passed also unique ID's for Notifications..!

```
 long timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();

 int i=(int) timestamp;

 mNotificationManager.notify(i, mBuilder.build());
```

Please help me find the error.

Answer (score 2):

You  need to add `PendingIntent` to your notification builder:

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

Read this article: [Creating a Simple Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#SimpleNotification)

Comment: @Phil-Thanx for ur kind reply...i have already implemented what u have wrote here...still i cannot know where i m doing wrong..!